# populate GridLayoutManager first by row and then by column

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I'm having an issue while populating a recycler view with a GridLayoutManager.

I need to fulfill the first row, and after this is complete, go to the second row. I did an algorithm that reorders the list so it's being shown properly and I can get the item clicked without doing any mapping-unmapping thing. This is working fine, but the trouble appears when all the items can be shown on the screen without scrolling.

For example, I have 4 items and I need to show them in a 2-row grid layout (horizontal layout). The screen has space for 3 items, so I need them to be in the first row, while the 4th item should be the only one in the second row.

To give you a picture of what I have by default:

```
0 2
1 3
```

And what I need is:

```
0 1 2
3
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
As requested, here is the code I'm using:

```
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
```

Comment: did you find a sloution

Answer (score 0):

When you are defining your gridLayoutManager, you specify the number of columns

```
RecyclerView rView = new RecyclerView(this);
rView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, <your number of columns>));
```

Setting this value to 3 (in your case) would result in three columns, with two rows. Your array adapter populates the fields from left to right, then top to bottom.

Comment: Failing this, you could add "null" or " " to your array until it is evenly divisible by the number of columns you want (in this instance, a total of 6 elements). This would populate two additional columns in the second row with nothing, but still adding them to the layout.

Comment: The first approach was the one I tried and didn't work. By default, it's not displaying the items as you mentioned (check at the question how it was ordering the items). The second approach shouldn't work! 
I ended reordering the whole list to match the expected result, but without a clear solution to solve this.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: How are you declaring your gridLayoutManager, can you update your answer with some of your existing code?

Comment: Updated. Remember that I want an horizontal grid!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve your issue but you can have dynamic columns based on items type or position (or similar logic)

```
val layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), columnsCount)
layoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object: GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
        return adapter.getColumnsCount(position)
    }
}
rvList.layoutManager = layoutManager
```

and in your adapter a method that returns the columns

```
fun getColumnsCount(position: Int): Int {
    return when (getItem(position).type) {
        ItemType.FIRST -> 1
        ItemType.SECOND -> 3
    }
}
```

======
If all you need is to fit the items on screen, you can have fixed width items and calculate how many fit the screen:

```
val columnCount = recyclerView.width / resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.grid_item_width)
```